# LINQ: How to query for the first sentence that contain a specified word

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am implementing a "deep search" feature within my MVC5 application. It queries many EF entities for keyword (string) matches.

It works great (thanks Linq!) except I need to perform some advanced string manipulation now.

The issue is that my "item.Description" field can be rather large sometimes. I just need to grab the first sentence from the description that contains the matching keyword.
I need to limit the result of that to 250 characters, so the UI doesn't look crazy. My controller returns an IQueryable object, which is just a class with 4 string properties.

Here are some examples of what the Item Description may look like:

```
"Represent clients in criminal and civil litigation and other legal proceedings, draw up legal documents, or manage or advise clients on legal transactions. May specialize in a single area or may practice broadly in many areas of law."
"Teach courses in criminal justice, corrections, and law enforcement administration. Includes both teachers primarily engaged in teaching and those who do a combination of teaching and research."
"Teach courses in law. Includes both teachers primarily engaged in teaching and those who do a combination of teaching and research."
```

Here is my LINQ code I am using to filter down my result set:

```
var keyword = "law";
var itemsByTitle = db.Items.Where(item => item.Description.Contains(keyword)).Select(item => new GlobalSearchResult { Id = item.Id, Match = item.Description, Title = item.Title, Type = "item" });
```

I need to expand on `item.Description` to do this advanced string/sentence manipulation.

The ideal results would/should be:

```
"May specialize in a single area or may practice broadly in many areas of law."
"Teach courses in criminal justice, corrections, and law enforcement administration."
"Teach courses in law."
```

I saw this example but it is for Linq to Objects, and I believe I am using Linq to Entities? The syntax is a bit different, although related. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693048.aspx

Is this advanced string/sentence manipulation possible in a single LINQ Entity query? If so, how can I get started? I am unsure if I should use regex here? Or a 2nd object to intersect on?

Comment: As a starter, I would break each description down into single sentence arrays/collections.  Then 'search' each descriptions collection for the first instance of the word "law" or whatever the keyword is.  Then return the first sentence that contains that keyword.  I would just pull (unless you have millions of results from the database) all the descriptions from the database, that way you could work with them using LINQ to objects.

Comment: Can you expand further on what you mean by advanced string/search manipulation? Do you want to pull all sentences with the word "law" inside and put it in your itemsByTitle

Comment: Yes @RahulJha that is exactly what I mean.